# Transform select statement

Tags: jdbc, jooq

How can i dynamically transform an SQL-Query?
I know there is a `Select.getSelect()`, but how can i add fields in the select-query?

Use-case: for a Rest-Query i have a lot of paginated resources and i have an abstraction to create the paginated-query. It takes the SelectConditionStep and adds the rest, depending on additional parameters. It works really well for simple queries, but for queries containing joins a little bit of transformation of the query would required. (Mainly because i can't naively limit the number results, since the join can be a one to many relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to keep a `List<Field<?>>` where you add the fields for your `select()` clause, and then create the `Select` statement only when you actually execute it, instead of passing a `Select` object around. Example:

```
List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<>();

// Just some examples:
fields.addAll(getDefaultFields());
fields.addAll(getFieldsFromUI());
fields.addAll(getCalculatedFields());

// Much later on, you finally create the statement:
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(fields)
   .from(...)
   .fetch();
```